# Filter the rows from one table based on matching columns values in another table with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark

I have table `A` and table `B` where I need to filter out the rows from table `A` with matching values on some columns from table `B`.

Below are some conditions to check and filter:

```
 1. A.c1 = B.c1, A.c2 = B.c2, A.c3 = B.c3, A.c4 = B.c4, A.c5 = B.c5
 2. A.c1 = 'ALL', A.c2 = B.c2, A.c3 = B.c3, A.c4 = B.c4, A.c5 = B.c5
 3. A.c1 = 'ALL', A.c2 = 'ALL', A.c3 = B.c3, A.c4 = B.c4, A.c5 = B.c5
 4. A.c1 = 'ALL', A.c2 = 'ALL', A.c3 = 'ALL', A.c4 = B.c4, A.c5 = B.c5
 5. A.c1 = 'ALL', A.c2 = B.c2, A.c3 = 'ALL', A.c4 = B.c4, A.c5 = B.c5
 6. ....

 32. A.c1 = 'ALL', A.c2 = 'ALL', A.c3 = 'ALL', A.c4 = 'ALL', A.c5 = 'ALL'
```

when A.cX is 'ALL' we match on other conditions of Table B and filter the rows.

And so on with all combinations that are 32.

What would be an efficient way to write SQL query or data frame operations.
[Example Filtered output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q6U6.jpg)

Comment: So you are looking to match columns c1-c5 and if A.cX = 'All' that should be treated as a match on A.cX?

Comment: Yeah match on A.cX in Table A and check the other matches in Table A and Table B